# Как сделать авто подстановку переменных из документации android studio в авто создаваемых методах?

Tags: android, android-studio

Что сделать в android studio чтобы она подставляла вместо i1,i2,i3 названия из документации.

Прописал -  new OnScr , затем прожал Tab и AndroidStudio вставила i1,i2,i3 вместо того что прописано в документации.

[image: как делает adnroid studio (сейчас)]

В документации написано [image: документация]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том что adnroid api 31 Platform, в adnroid studio плохо расписан ( документация и методы , в них вообще информации нет).

Чтобы решить проблему нужно в *Project stucture* выбрать **Complite Sdk version** ниже 31 и **Target Sdk version** ниже 31.